# Keep Indexes Stagnant Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, indexing

I am attempting to sort the list where -1 is stagnant where the rest of the numbers are sorted in height. The output should be [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190].

```
a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
z = [n for n, m in enumerate(a) if m == -1]
y = sorted(a)
print(y)
print (z)
```

Here are the results

```
y=[-1, -1, -1, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
z=[0, 4, 5]
output should be= [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: That is output should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the elements that are not *-1* and fill it back to the original list:

```
a = [-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]
s = sorted(x for x in a if x != -1)
s
# [150, 160, 170, 180, 190]

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v != -1:
        a[i] = s.pop(0)

a
# [-1, 150, 160, 170, -1, -1, 180, 190]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to use sorted to do this. I'm thinking that you could do this:

```
nOnes = []
for i,k in enumerate(a):
    if k == -1:
        nOnes.append((i,a.pop(i)))
y = sorted(a)
for m,n in nOnes:
    y.insert(m,n)
```

It's not incredibly pythonic, but it works.

Comment: This error came up:TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Ah sorry, fixed it. Psidom's answer is probably better anyway.